# Curious about Lambda Expression

Tags: c#

[Lambda Expressions (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)
Does this Microsoft page give all necessary information to learn lambda or is it a big topic to learn from other sources? I am learning C#, would like to know if microsoft c# language guide can give me all necessary information to become proficient in C#?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think I remember using that guide a couple of years ago and found it quite good. It probably contains most information you need. Keep in mind that lambdas take the symbol, not the actual value when you instantiate it. In other words... If you loop over a collection and use the item in the loop in a lambda expression, every lambda you create there will use the last iterated value. There are probably other edge-cases too

Comment: Lambda usage is not a big topic, just a useful one :)  Once you get used to the syntax, the only remaining tricky parts are interaction with delegates (sometimes you are forced to cast =P), and bugs related to for-loops.  The article briefly mentions expression trees, which are a deeper topic, and are only related to Lambdas.  You will see constant lambda usage in LINQ, so the more you use LINQ, the more familiar you will get with Lambdas.  LINQ is also a much bigger topic than Lambdas.

Answer (score 3):

Reading book and other information on web won't make you proficient on that topic. You need to do some practical work to actually understand and be able to apply. Skill != Knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

I think MSDN help is enough for being proficient at any given language concept.

Given that you follow all those small examples and practices available on MSDN, you should be pretty clear on the fundamentals.

Remember, you will not learn anything until you practice.

Answer (score 1):

Read "C# in Depth" by Jon Skeet ...

A short answer is that Lambda expression is one of the way (easy) to write delegates (in case of Linq To Objects). In case of Provider (like Linq to SQL) it acts as Expression Tree, which provider can parse to create appropriate query for underlying data source.

You can also learn it by writing linq queries for objects and sql. Compare the actual code created by C# with the help of Reflector.

Answer (score 1):

Two other good introductions to C# lambda expressions:

- [Explaining C# lambda statements in one sentence (and LINQ in about 10)](http://blogs.windwardreports.com/davidt/2011/04/explaining-c-lambda-statements-in-one-sentence-and-linq-in-about-10.html)
- [LINQ in Action](http://linqinaction.net/) (I like C# in Depth but think this is better for LINQ.)

The first (disclaimer - my blog) will give you a quick explanation of the fundamental concepts. The book provides complete coverage of all relevant topics.